# How can I spool a column value with the width of the column

Tags: database, oracle, spool

I want to do a spool from a table (Example TABLE T)

```
TABLE T
  col1 number(10)   with suppose value of 2 
  col2 varchar2(10) with suppose value of "HI"
```

And in the result spool file from this table I wish to get the data in such a way that it will represent the dimension of the column too.

```
0000000002;HI          ;
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below select query to get  required result

```
select LPAD(col1,10,0),RPAD(col2,10,' ') from T;
```

If need dynamic to get length from table definition below query will help

```
select (select LPAD(col1,data_length,0)
from T,all_tab_columns
where table_name='T'
and column_name='COL1'),

(select RPAD(col2,data_length,' ')
from T,all_tab_columns
where table_name='T'
and column_name='COL2') from dual;
```

Comment: Yes, I need it dynamic , yey  I will return tomorrow with an update if it worked. :D thanks @kanagaraj